# Outlook: Save Excel attachment and change file extension

Tags: vba, outlook

I have no prior experience in `VBA` and found a solution to the first part of my question here.
So, I was able to make the "Save Excel attachment"-part work with the code below.

Now, since the attachment is a `.xls` file and gives me a corrupted file message when opening (other worksheets pull data from this saved file), I would like to save it automatically as a .`xlsx` file.

I tried to find a solution but the things I have tried would not work. Hope to find some help here. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime - 1, "yyyymmdd_")    
    saveFolder = "THIS IS MY FOLDER"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
       Next    

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how saving it as `xlsx` is going to help if it's `xls` - or are you trying to automate an instance of Excel 2007+ to open and re-save it? I would probably look more into why I was getting the corrupted file message

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am open to any solutions. What I ultimately would like to see is that the file being saved can be "read" by other excel files without me having to manually open/save as xlsx. Sorry that my description might not be 100% clear, totally new to this. I also think the reason for the corrupted file message is coming from the Outlook security settings (or at least that is what I read somewhere), I will not be able to change those settings though.

Comment: This is the actual message I get when opening the file: "The file you are trying to open <filename.xls> is in a different format than specified by the file extension. verify the file is not corrupted and is from trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

Comment: Is it actually an xls file then?

Comment: Check that you are saving the correct attachment. If the message was not sent as plain text then it may have another attachment which is the formatted message in html - you don't want to save that as .xls

Comment: @lordpeter I think it is a plain text message, but since I have no clue how to find that out, I can't say for sure.

Comment: @user1922391 You could "debug.print objAtt.Displayname" to see the name of the attachment, and check that it is indeed the .xls file that you are expecting and not something else.

Comment: @user1922391 Also you can check the format using the message's .BodyFormat property. (1=Plain, 2=HTML, 3= RTF, 4=Unknown).

Comment: I have seen this problem before (and never liked it). The only solution I came up with is to open the file in an XL environment and then save it to `.xlsx` format.

Answer (score 1):

You specify fileFormat like this

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

or

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileFormat:=51

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840717(v=office.14).aspx

File Formats here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx?